# New to Python. Can someone explain this line of code to me?

Tags: python

So i'm new to Python and i'm going through a Python course I purchased and they have a quiz. The last question was to print the last 6 letters of the string. The code is below:

```
welcome_message = "Hello and welcome to the land of Python"

print(f"The last 6 letters of the welcome message:\n'{welcome_message}'\nare: '{welcome_message[len(welcome_message)-6:]}'")
```

The output would then be:

```
The last 6 letters of the welcome message:
'Hello and welcome to the land of Python'
are: Python
```

This is from the solution. I am not understanding what's going on here: `'{welcome_message[len(welcome_message)-6:]}'`

I don't understand why the solution included the `len()` function.

Why can't I just do `'{welcome_message[-6:]}`'
?

Comment: "Why can't I just do '{welcome_message[-6:]}' ?" - you can. Not all code you find is good code.

Comment: ``len`` is the length of the string. So you are printing  everything  from its length - 6 to the end of the string, in other words, the last 6 characters.

Comment: You can do it both ways

Comment: yeah, you can do it, there are multiple ways of coding the same thing, with experience one is able to write clean and simple code.

Answer (score 2):

You'll get the same output with this too.
In python -1 index is same as the last index and when its blank it means starting or ending depending on where you put it. for eg.

```
welcome_message[:]
```

will print the entire string.

As for your question you can use `welcome_message[34:]` which instead of counting yourself a better way of writing is `welcome_message[len(welcome_message)-6:]`.
But an even better way of writing is the solution you pointed out, i.e,
`welcome_message[-6:]`

Answer (score 1):

> print(f"The last 6 letters of the welcome message:\n'{welcome_message}'\nare: '{welcome_message[len(welcome_message)-6:]}'")

Here is what is happening **welcome_message** is a variable which can have infinite letters/character/number/symbols/strings etc.. which the system does not know first hand...
So **welcome_message[len...]** first finds how many characters are there in the string, not words... I say characters because we supply `len()` function with the welcome_message variable which has just 1 string... so thus far i hope I explained what happened till
`{welcome_message[len(welcome_message)]}` and then its just plain old -6 arithmetic operation from the count that is returned by the `len()` fn

Comment: Ahhhh I totally get it now. It's basically doing 39-6.

39 coming from the len() function and -6 coming from the last six letters.

Thanks!!

Comment: Exactly.. that the ```len()``` is one of the built-in functions that Python provides out of the box here is the complete list of such functions that I think you should keep handy...

https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html

Also if my answer has provided you with a solution please mark it as an answer it helps a lot on stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

```
welcome_message = "Hello and welcome to the land of Python"

print(f"The last 6 letters of the welcome message:\n'{welcome_message}'\nare: '{welcome_message[len(welcome_message)-6:]}'")
```

1. Here welcome_message is storing a string which is "Hello and welcome to the land of Python".
2. while printing if we will add `\n` in a string it will output a newline in answer.
3. len(welcome_message)-6 = 39-6 = 33.
4. in string slicing `s[i:]` it will give output as a string which includes the character from `i` to end of the string.
5. Hence  `welcome_message[len(welcome_message)-6:]` will output the characters from index of 33 to 39th index.
6. Remember that `" "` is also a character of the string.